# Parâmetro JS para arquivo PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Olá.. Estou com um problema no qual estou encontrando dificuldades, talvez pelo meu pouco conhecimento em JS.

Possuo uma função JavaScript que chama um arquivo PHP:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
...

 events: "events.php"
</script>
```

Quando é chamado esse arquivo PHP (events.php) tudo que precisa acontecer, acontece. É realizada uma busca nesse arquivo e retornado um JSON... Ok... minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Preciso, ao chamar o arquivo 'events.php' passar uma variavel como parametro, para pegar o valor dela dentro do arquivo chamado. De qual forma posso fazer isso? Passar uma variavel php como parametro na função JS que chama um arquivo PHP?

Answer (score 3):

Porque não fazer um `$_GET`?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
...
 var parametro = 123;
 events: "events.php?param=" +parametro;
</script>
```

No ficheiro events.php:

```
$parametro = $_GET['param']; // 123
```

Comment: Claro, isso mesmo. Eu estava recebendo com _REQUEST na outra página, por isso estava dando erro. Obrigado.

Comment: AInda bem que ajudou

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que utilize jQuery e AJAX para esse procedimento, porque pode acontecer algum erro no procedimento e você possui uma gama muito maior de recursos para lidar com os retornos do protocolo HTTP.
Você adiciona o jQuery ao seu projeto e cria um script mais ou menos assim:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "events.php",
  data: { dado1: "blablabla", dado2: "blablabla" },
  success: function (msg){
    //aqui ficará o retorno da página
    alert (msg);
  },
  error: function (){
    //Faz alguma coisa caso não obtenha sucesso
  }
});
```

Para utilizar melhor essa função recomendo a leitura da documentação [neste link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).